# How to override the model.Manager.create() method in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have plenty of `Hardware` models which have a `HardwareType` with various characteristics. Like so:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class HardwareType(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

    # some characteristics of this particular piece of hardware
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=3)
    # and more [...]        

class Hardware(models.Model):

    type = models.ForeignKey(HardwareType)

    # some attributes
    is_installed = models.BooleanField()
    location_installed = models.TextField()
    # and more [...]
```

If I wish to add a new `Hardware` object, I first have to retrieve the `HardwareType` every time, which is not very DRY:

```
tmp_hd_type = HardwareType.objects.get(name='NG35001')
new_hd = Hardware.objects.create(type=tmp_hd_type, is_installed=True, ...)
```

Therefore, I have tried to override the `HardwareManager.create()` method to automatically import the type when creating new `Hardware` like so:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class HardwareType(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

    # some characteristics of this particular piece of hardware
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=3)
    # and more [...] 

class HardwareManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'type' in kwargs and kwargs['type'] is str:
            kwargs['type'] = HardwareType.objects.get(name=kwargs['type'])
        super(HardwareManager, self).create(*args, **kwargs)       

class Hardware(models.Model):
    objects = HardwareManager()

    type = models.ForeignKey(HardwareType)

    # some attributes
    is_installed = models.BooleanField()
    location_installed = models.TextField()
    # and more [...]

# so then I should be able to do:
new_hd = Hardware.objects.create(type='ND35001', is_installed=True, ...)
```

But I keep getting errors and really strange behaviors from the ORM (I don't have them right here, but I can post them if needed). I've searched in the Django documentation and the SO threads, but mostly I end up on solutions where:

- the `Hardware.save()` method is overridden (should I get the `HardwareType` there ?) or,
- the manager defines a new `create_something` method which calls `self.create()`.

I also started digging into the code and saw that the `Manager` is some special kind of `QuerySet` but I don't know how to continue from there. I'd really like to replace the `create` method in place and I can't seem to manage this. What is preventing me from doing what I want to do?

Comment: Another thing you can do. Is just creating the FK with the to_field pointing to the name field . And then you can save the type string. Like so : type = models.ForeignKey(HardwareType, to_field='name') . And so new_hd = Hardware.objects.create(type='ND35001', is_installed=True .. ) will work without overwriting manager. ND35001 should exist and be unique. So should work as you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The insight from [Alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair)'s answer helped a lot to catch both strings and unicode strings, but what was actually missing was a `return` statement before the call to `super(HardwareManager, self).create(*args, **kwargs)` in the `HardwareManager.create()` method.

The errors I was getting in my tests yesterday evening (being tired when coding is not a good idea :P) were `ValueError: Cannot assign None: [...] does not allow null values.` because the subsequent usage of `new_hd` that I had `create()`d was `None` because my `create()` method didn't have a `return`. What a stupid mistake !

Final corrected code:

```
class HardwareManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'type' in kwargs and isinstance(kwargs['type'], basestring):
            kwargs['type'] = HardwareType.objects.get(name=kwargs['type'])
        return super(HardwareManager, self).create(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the traceback, I think the problem is on this line.

```
    if 'type' in kwargs and kwargs['type'] is str:
```

This is checking whether `kwargs['type']` is the same object as `str`, which will always be false.

In Python 3, to check whether `kwargs['type'] is a string, you should do:

```
    if 'type' in kwargs and isinstance(kwargs['type'], str):
```

If you are using Python 2, you should use `basestring`, to catch byte strings and unicode strings.

```
    if 'type' in kwargs and isinstance(kwargs['type'], basestring):
```

Comment: I'll try this in a couple of hours and get back to you with the errors (if any). Thanks !

Comment: In 2.x you can use `isinstance(foo, basestring)` to catch both unicode and str.

Comment: @DanielRoseman does the `Manager.create` use the `model.save` method defined in the model or not?

Comment: @DhiaTN a good way to get better as a developer is to have a look at the code for yourself

Answer (score 1):

I was researching the same problem as you and decided not to use an override.

In my case making just another method made more sense given my constraints.

```
class HardwareManager(models.Manager):
    def create_hardware(self, type):
        _type = HardwareType.objects.get_or_create(name=type)
        return self.create(type = _type ....)
```