# What does django's Manager.create() method do?

Tags: django, github, model-view-controller, model

I was poking around in the `rest_framework` trying to figure out how it works, and came across a call to `Model.objects.create()`, but I can't for the life of me find the `create()` method for django model managers in the docs or the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/manager.py). It looks to be dynamically generated. What does it do, exactly? Where can I find its code? If I wanted to override it, what would my implementation have to do? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899520/how-to-override-the-model-manager-create-method-in-django) but it only says to call the `super().create()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's manager will look for the same method on a `QuerySet` in case that method does not exists in the `Manager`. So it will call the [**`.create()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create) on the underlying `QuerySet`, which is [implemented as <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/query.py#L668-L676):

> ```
> def create(self, **kwargs):
>     """
>     Create a new object with the given kwargs, saving it to the database
>     and returning the created object.
>     """
>     obj = self.model(**kwargs)
>     self._for_write = True
>     obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
>     return obj
> ```

It will thus create a model object with the passed keywords, and save it with `force_insert=True` to slightly improve efficiency, and return the item created at the database.